# Delphi : Prevent TPageControl Hint from showing on contained items

Tags: delphi, vcl, hints

I have a form with the following components: A `TPageControl` containing a single `TTabSheet`, containing a `TEdit`.

I want a hint "Hello" displayed when I mouse over the pagecontrol tab, and *no* hint displayed when I mouse over the TEdit.

The `PageControl` has a `hint= "Hello"`, and `showhint = true`. This works as expected.

The `TEdit` has `showhint = false`, `parentshowhint = false`, and `hint` is empty.

But, I still get a "Hello" hint whn I mouseover the TEdit. How can I stop this?

Here's the .dfm, if you're interested.

```
object Form65: TForm65
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form65'
  ClientHeight = 258
  ClientWidth = 290
  OldCreateOrder = False
  ShowHint = True
  TextHeight = 13
  object PageControl1: TPageControl
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 290
    Height = 258
    Hint = 'Bar'
    ActivePage = TabSheet1
    Align = alClient
    TabOrder = 0
    object TabSheet1: TTabSheet
      Caption = 'TabSheet1'
      object Edit3: TEdit
        Left = 72
        Top = 67
        Width = 121
        Height = 21
        ParentShowHint = False
        ShowHint = False
        TabOrder = 0
        Text = 'tab1'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a TApplicationEvents control to your form, and use the OnShowHint event:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1ShowHint(var HintStr: string;
  var CanShow: Boolean; var HintInfo: THintInfo);
begin
  CanShow := HintInfo.HintControl <> Edit1;
end;
```

If you do not have the TApplicationEvents object in (e.g. if you are using a very old version of Delphi), then you can use (in FormCreate, for instance)

```
Application.OnShowHint := ApplicationEvents1ShowHint
```

to set the event handler manually.

## Update

If you have more than one control in the TTabSheet, then you might have the same problem with them all. Then you might be interested in

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1ShowHint(var HintStr: string;
  var CanShow: Boolean; var HintInfo: THintInfo);
begin
  CanShow := not SameStr(HintStr, PageControl1.Hint) or (HintInfo.HintControl = TabSheet1);
end;
```

## Update 2

If you have several TTabSheets in the TPageControl, and want all sheets to display the hint, but non of the child controls, then you can do

```
  CanShow := not SameStr(HintStr, PageControl1.Hint) or
    ((HintInfo.HintControl is TTabSheet) and
      (TTabSheet(HintInfo.HintControl).PageControl = PageControl1));
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a 'just set property X=false' solution, but this will do just fine!

Comment: Maybe this works?: `CanShow := HintInfo.HintControl.ShowHint`

Comment: @mjustin: No, that does not work. (Try it yourself!) If `ShowHint = false`, then the procedure is never called with this control as the `HintControl`.

Comment: Ok, maybe this: `CanShow := HintInfo.HintControl.Tag = MY_MAGIC_SHOWHINT_VALUE`

Comment: @mjustin: Sure, if all controls have `ShowHint = true` and all that are to display the hint have this tag.